# NGINX rewrite (sorry)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I was trying to find sollytion? but fails

I want to redirect clients to another site, but part of url (XXX) must be the same

```
original    www.mysite.com/card.aspx?service_id=XXX&pageuid=card
rewrite to  https://some.othersite.com/?s=XXX
```

XXX are same

Who can help? If it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ /card(.*)$ {
if ($args ~* /?service_id=[0-9]+) {
    rewrite ^ https://some.othersite.com?s=$arg_service_id? permanent;
    }
}
```

hope it will be usefull for somebody.